# What is the approximation ratio between $n \choose k$ and $(n/k\cdot e)^k$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

My teamwork claimed that a good approximation for $n \choose k$ is $(\frac{n}{k}\cdot e)^k$. he said to me that in most cases $n \choose k$ is really closed to $(\frac{n}{k}\cdot e)^k$ (up to factor of 1.25).

What is the worst case approximation ratio between   $n \choose k$ and $(\frac{n}{k}\cdot e)^k$? I know that it can be bounded by $e$ (since $ (\frac{n}{k})^k< {n \choose k} < (\frac{n}{k}\cdot e)^k $), my question is there is a better approximation ratio for this.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: This may be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#ounds%20and%20asymptotic%20formulas